# Can't pthreads access variables from the main() function?

Tags: c++, pthreads

```
int main()
{
   int i; 
   pthread_t t; 
}
```

Can t not see i? t is  created inside main, right? That means it must be using the same shared memory main() is using? How do I make it see i without making i a global variable?

Answer (score 5):

What? `t` is a thread, it doesn't really "see" anything. Strictly, it's a variable that represents a thread -- you haven't actually created a thread -- but assuming you do create one, it runs in the same process as `main()`, so it shares memory space in that sense, but it doesn't share the scope of main. The *functions* which run in that thread can see whatever variables are in scope for those functions.

You could pass a pointer to `i` as the user data pointer to `pthread_create`. Or if you need to access more than just `i`, you could pass a pointer to some structure which contains (among other things) a pointer to `i`, and so on.

Example code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

void *thread_entry_point(void *data) {
    int *idata = static_cast<int*>(data);
    std::cout << "thread: i = " << *idata << "\n";
    *idata = 23;
    return const_cast<char*>("might as well return something");
}

int main() {
    int i = 12;
    pthread_t thr;

    int err = pthread_create(&thr, 0, thread_entry_point, &i);
    if (err == 0) {
        void *result;
        pthread_join(thr, &result);

        std::cout << "main: result = " << static_cast<const char*>(result) << "\n";
        std::cout << "main: i = " << i << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "error creating thread: " << err << " " << std::strerror(err) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Well... you can pass `&i` as an argument to the thread to put it in the thread function's scope.

Comment: @André: yep, I'm getting there :-)

Comment: &Andre. Can somebody paste the full working code to show how it works. Obviously I am new to Pthread.

Answer (score 4):

pthreads aren't special. For instance, the following code has the same "problem":

```
void foo()
{
  i = 5;
}
int main()
{
   int i; 
   foo();
}
```

Surely `foo` is called by `main`, so they're even on the same thread. Yet `foo` doesn't see the `int` in `main`. The solution is simple: if `foo` needs an `int`, `main` should pass that:

```
void foo(int& i)
{
  i = 5;
}
int main()
{
   int i; 
   foo(i);
}
```

With threads, the situation is the same: pass what you need to share.

Comment: Can I just pass pointers?  I heard if I need to free something passed, I need to pass a pointer to pointer to for example a malloc'ed struct.

Comment: @mLstudent33: You might be confusing C and C++. `malloc` and pointers to pointers are typical for C. You technically can use them in C++, but that's only so you can use C libraries from within C++ code. Also, note that this is a very old question. Since 2011, C++ uses `std::thread`.